# What are all Gibb's rules on NCIS and how many rules are there?

Tags: ncis

On *NCIS* Gibb's and his team always refer to some set of rules and their numbers.

But is there an actual ordered list of those rules or are these just unrelated throwaway lines? Do we know how many rules there are and what all of the rules in numerical order are?

Comment: This again isn't banal trivia. Asking about all mentioned rules in the show adds to the understanding of the show. Just like listing out Thano's snap list in Infinity War. Also, the link in the possible answer in the comment isn't from IMDB so the off-topic message doesn't make sense. Please dont broaden the horizon of off-topic(trivia) questions

Comment: Why is that link gone?  This question, while a list question, yielded a great resource.  Removing the link doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger It was an answer in the comments. Either we deem this question off-topic and don't want to encourage inappropriate questions by answering them in the comments or we deem it a proper question and worthy of a proper answer. If that link rots there in the comments, *noone* is going to write an actual answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Ncisfanwiki](http://www.ncisfanwiki.com/page/NCIS%3A+Gibbs%27+Rules) currently lists 36 rules. If you've seen the show, you know that the rules are numbered. The rule with the highest number on the aforementioned site is rule 70. Some numbers have multiple rules, for example there are two rules 1:

> Never let suspects stay together.

and

> Never screw (over) your partner.

To answer your question, 36 unique rules have been mentioned in the series, some with the same number. If we assume the rules form an ordered list without skipping any numbers than there are more than 70 (because of some rules having the same number).